# How can I process pixels on screen if they don't mirror in /dev/fb0

Tags: linux, x11, framebuffer, raspberry-pi4

I am currently working on a Raspberry Pi 4 with retropie and want to process the colours on the screen to do some cool stuff with LEDs. My Idea was to check the Linux framebuffer (/dev/fb0). It works for the command line itself, but as soon if I start a programm nothing changes, I noticed that if I echo urandom to fb0 it fills the console with random pixels but not the programm that runs on top (emulationstation).

As you might alreay expect I do not have much expirience with Linux graphics, so my Question is how I can get the pixel printed on the next or current frame. I found some stuff regarding X11 on the System but I didn't made much progress looking that way.

I hope someone can poke me in the right direction and thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you need to be root (or a member of the appropriate group) to use the framebuffer. Is your program checking for errors?

Comment: Also, instead of reading the framebuffer, it may be better to ask X11 for an image of the screen. Look for `XShmGetImage`.

Comment: Yes I checked every status code and they all returned as expected, but I think your tipp regarding XShmGetImage will help me, I will look into it.